# JQuery .load() function not working on WebKit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use the jQuery.load() function, and it works on Firefox, but not on Safari and Chrome. The odd part is that it works on mobile Safari.

All of the posts I found on this subject appeared old and outdated.

Does anyone have a solution to fix this problem?

Here is sample code from my page:

```
<div class="navButton"></div>
<script>
$(".navButton").load("bottomNav.html");
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery `.load()` works just fine on webkit so there is nothing generically wrong with it on webkit.  There must be something specific about your use of it (beyond the code you've shown to us) that is causing a problem.  Can you point us to a web-page that illustrates your issue?  Have you looked in the console for any errors that might either indicate what is the issue with `.load()` or might be stopping script execution before it gets to this line?

Comment: Here is the page that is causing me the problems: http://yellowtailderby.com/index2.html the bottom navigation should appear twice, once in HTML5 and once in Flash, however, only the Flash appears in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error console tells the story here.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
      http://yellowtailderby.com/jquery-2.1.0.js

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

So, when you try to execute:

```
$(".navButton").load("bottomNav.html");
```

The `$` symbol is not defined because jQuery is not successfully loaded.

The issue seems to be that this:

```
http://yellowtailderby.com/jquery-2.1.0.js
```

does not exist (gets a 404 error) so this script tag:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

is not working properly.  The fix is to either correct the script tag or make sure that particular file is properly located on your server at that path.

---

I am getting the exact same error in Firefox, so I suspect that maybe you have that file in your browser cache in Firefox (so it's getting loaded via cache), but it doesn't actually exist on the server.   The Firefox reports:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://yellowtailderby.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"
```

Comment: Thanks for finding this bug. Yes, I had forgotten to upload the JQuery file to the server. I had one more quick question, when I try to load the file locally, it does not show the content from the .load() function, and in the console it says: [Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (bottomNav.html, line 0) and [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://FILEPATH/bottomNav.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index2.html, line 0), two error that are not present when the file is viewed online.

Comment: @JakeChasan - I believe that the browser does not allow ajax calls to retrieve local files on your own hard drive (even when the host HTML page is local) which means that `.load()` won't work locally.   Some browsers (like Chrome) have command line options to override this for development reasons only.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The interesting thing about this, is that another file (a blank test file) calls the load function the same way in a local browser, and loads without a problem. This file is blank except for the code I posted above and the JQuery import script. Do you know why this works and the other file does not?

Comment: @JakeChasan - My guess is that it has to do with exactly how the path is specified and how Chrome decides what is and isn't a same-origin.  Without seeing the exact code (and probably running it locally), we can only really guess.  In any case, you can run Chrome with the `allow-file-access-from-files` command line argument to work-around it.  See http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/ for how to specify this argument on some platforms.